# PHPUnit's Skeleton Generator scripts doesn't exist

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I had been trying to use PHPUnit on Netbeans so I installed it using pear, however,
when I try to set up the path to the Skeleton Generator scripts(phpunit-skelgen.bat) in the options menu, I am unable to find the path to the phpunit-skelgen.bat.Only
the PHPUnit script exists in (D:\xampp\php\phpunit.bat).I've read couple of tutorials on how to install but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install it from **composer** :

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit-skeleton-generator": "*"
    }
}
```

Or directly download and use the phar :

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-skelgen.phar
php phpunit-skelgen.phar
```

Comment: Please note that the phpunit-skeleton-generator project is not being maintained since 2014. Although I still use it and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 6):

Although the skeleton generator is mentioned in the PHPUnit documentation, it is not bundled with PHPUnit, you have to download it separately here https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-skeleton-generator